# Find coordinate in each closed field in contour plot

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, matplotlib, coordinates, contour

I need to extract one coordinate pair and the color for each closed field in several generated contour plots.

I know how to extract the coordinates along the paths, but is it somehow possible to extract the data for the fields between the paths?

[Contourplot, with one arbitrary point in each closed field:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NW5nA.png)

Any suggestions?

Thankful for all the help I can get!

Best Regards Viktor

Comment: So you want (x,y,color) for each non-blank point in the plot? Do you also need to segment the plot, find coordinates range, and find colors from legend? Or we can assume you already know them?

Comment: I want (x,y,color) for any given point in of each closed field in the plot

Comment: The most difficult part is to segment the plot from the rest of the image, and retrieve x and y ranges. You want to do this programmatically or you allow user interaction to do that? Also, post the code you tried so far.

Comment: Sorry, did not mean to post the last comment....Thx for your response! Basically I need (x,y,color) for one point in each closed field. It doesn't matter which point. You can assume that I have the coordinates for all the segments. I do not have the colors from the legend. Best regards Viktor

Comment: Are you talking about reading the image (with opencv for example?) and read the pixel-locations? The best thing would be if I somehow could extract this data from the contour plot object that I have generated with. Do you think its possble? Again, thx for your help!